# Can an XML attribute value be a single white space in NOTEPAD++ v6.7.5?

Tags: xml, notepad++

In the following XML tag

```
<Environment ignoreCase="yes" startFunc="(" stopFunc=")" paramSeparator="," terminal=";" additionalWordChar = "-"/>
```

the startFunc attribute value must be replaced by a " " [one single white space instead of "("].
Is there any way to make the XML parser to not remove the white space ? 
I have tried special chars for spaces, with no luck, the encoding used are "UTF-8" and "windows-1252".

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

I'm trying to configure notepad++ so that the "auto-completion" with "function parameters hints" fires after I hit the space bar [the default value is "("].

Based on Michael Kay's answer, I understood that the problem came from notepad++ and not from XML and found this link:

http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Editing_Configuration_Files#Autocompletion.2C_aka_API.2C_files

The note saying: "Spaces can't be used as the character for the attributes and additionalWordChar is still not working (Notepad++ v.6.5.2) but maybe in future releases... " is very clear, however the additionalWordChar attribrute is already working.

I'm using npp v.6.7.5 ... is there anyway to overcome this ?

Comment: What is your `the XML parser`?

Comment: The file is "parsed" by  Notepad++, I don't know anymore details about that

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is entirely possible for the value of an attribute to be a single space character. If it's not working for you then we need to see more detail of exactly what you are doing and exactly how it is failing.